# What is the best way to add i18n to an existing custom CMS system (build with C#)?

Tags: c#, .net, internationalization

I am currently responsible for an existing CMS, built a few years ago with C# .Net and a few clients are requesting to have their website in Spanish. The websites are pre-populated with pages from a library and currently the application has no support for i18n. What is the quickest way to allow the client to have his website in Spanish? And what is the best way to allow any language?

I understand those are two different answers, but I want to plan for future and at the same time provide a quick solution to please the clients.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest i18n solutions usually involve using a string dictionary for any text in the program.

Instead of doing things like:

```
TextBox t = new TextBox();
t.Text = "Hello, user!";
```

You'd do something like:

```
TextBox t = new TextBox();
t.Text = i18nStringDictionary["HelloUserMessage"]; //some people prefer an enum to 
//bare strings in this case
```

Where i18nStringDictionary is a global or semi global dictionary. Then, on app start up you can initialize it with the proper values from a file as dictated by a config file. You'll have one file for each language. Illustrating the above example, in your english file, you'd have:

```
HelloUserMessage, "Hello, user!"
//More message pairs in english
```

and in your spanish file:

```
HelloUserMessage, "Hola, usario!"
//More message pairs in spanish.
```

Finally, you'd parse these pairs into a dictionary type.

Of course, this is only if you want to roll your own, but it demonstrates what most i18n libraries do under the covers. Otherwise, you can use the built in features of C# (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688096.aspx), or find plenty of third party tools.

In any case, it probably won't be quick at all, since it involves replacing all string literals in the site/program with references to some dictionary or library. Once it is done, though, you will only need to do the translation and set config file variable and you'll be good to go.

Final edit:

Since you are talking about a website, you probably have views or templates with text in them as well. These would generally also need to be replaced with references to a string library.

Answer (score 0):

Just search for **ASP.NET globalization and localization**.

#### Resource Files

You could add resource files (RESX) for all static text used in the ASP.NET controls. 
[Here is an MSDN article even covering Spanish](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427%28v=vs.140%29.aspx).

Creating a new RESX file in Visual Studio will give you a table view. Let's say you add **Text.resx** to the project. This will be the default language.

```
| Name           | Value         |
| HelloWorld     | Hello World ! |
| WelcomeMessage | Welcome !     |
```

You can now reference the Names in the code behind:

```
Label label = new Label();
label.Text = Text.WelcomeMessage;
```

Or you can set the binding in the designer

```
<asp:Label ID="Button1" runat="server" 
Text="<%$ Resources:Text, WelcomeMessage %>" />
```

#### Switching language

Now to add another language simply create a new file named Text.*language-country*.resx. So in your case **Text.es-ES.resx**.

Each entry you add here will overwrite the default language when you switch to Spanish. If it is missing, then the default value will be shown.

```
| Name           | Value         |
| WelcomeMessage | ¡Bienvenidos! |
```

You can switch languages by changing the culture property of the current thread

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = 
new CultureInfo("es-ES");
```

Otherwise the language can be set depending on browser settings.
More info here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647353.aspx

#### Translation

RESX files are actually XML documents that can be embedded into an assembly are referenced as content files.
So you could send the default resource file to a translation agency for them to edit. Just remind them not to translate any entries in the Name column.